# Django store to db using POST without django form

Tags: django, post

I'm new in Django. 
Besides using Django form to access django database, I'm now trying to use ***POST request*** to do that. But it's doesn't work, there is no data store to database.

In views.py

```
def event_join(request):
    print ("event_join")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userID=request.GET['usrID']

        join_id = e_id
        usr = Usr.objects.get(usr_id=userID)
        if join_id in usr.join_ids.split(','):
         print "Joined already!"
        else:
            usr.join_ids += ',' + join_id
            usr.save()

            Event_member.objects.create(
                e_id = join_id,
                usr_id = userID,
                star_to_emer = 0,
                star_from_emer = 0,
            )

    return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'unfinished_events': Event.objects.filter(finish=0)})
```

And button active function join

```
var join = function() {
  console.log(userID);
  $.post('/event_join', {usrID:userID}, function(data) {});
}
```

In urls.py - urlpatterns

```
url(r'^event_join/$', views.event_join, name='event_join'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking the `GET` parameters in a `POST` call. Modify your code at least to do:

```
userID = request.POST['usrID']
```

Next, you're posting to `/event_join`, but your `urls.py` is configured to handle the path with the trailing slash, `^event_join/$`. Make them consistent.